# Adding a new user to swift (Open stack )

Tags: openstack-swift

I have installed swift 1.4.8 and I want to know how to  Add a new user to swift 1.4.8 .In swift 1.4.7 version ,user was added using swauth authentication but ,swauth command is not available in newer version(swift 1.4.8).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Ubuntu, you can install swauth by

```
apt-get install swauth
```

Also, make sure you enable swauth in proxy-server.conf.
For example,

```
[pipeline:main]
pipeline = healthcheck cache swauth proxy-server 

[filter:swauth]
use = egg:swauth#swauth
set log_name = root
default_swift_cluster = https://127.0.0.1:8080/v1
```